# What is a decidable fragment?

Tags: terminology, definition, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I read everywhere that description logics are decidable fragments of first-order logic. What does this mean? What is a decidable fragment of first-order logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A decidable logic is one where, given a statement, you can compute whether or not that statement is true in the logic.

A fragment of a logic is a subset of that logic obtained by imposing syntactic restrictions. The fragment has the same semantics, but possibly fewer well-formed formulae.

So a decidable fragment of first-order logic is a syntactically-restricted subset of first-order logic in which truth is computable.

Answer (score 3):

It is a "subset" of first-order logic that is [decidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_(logic)).

Another example is [Monadic predicate calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monadic_predicate_calculus) :

> in which all relation symbols are monadic (that is, they take only one argument), and there are no function symbols. This means that all atomic formulas are thus of the form $P(x)$.

In the case of a logical system, *decidability* means that :

> there is an effective method for determining whether arbitrary formulas are theorems of the logical system. For example, propositional logic is decidable, because the truth-table method can be used to determine whether an arbitrary propositional formula is logically valid.